# How to find out the total number of connections to an Activemq broker?

Tags: numbers, activemq-classic, connection

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.3.2. My app is a distributed system that creates lots of connections to the AMQ broker. Right now, my app occasionally runs into issues such as the producer stops producing messages, the AMQ broker non-responding, etc. I'm interested to find out the total number of connections to my AMQ broker, but I couldn't find this number anywhere in my JConsole where I can find out other numbers like total number of topics, queues, etc.

Does anyone know how to find out the total number of connections to a AMQ broker?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the total number of connections to your broker, you can look that up in JMX under:

org.apache.activemq.Connection.[Protocol]

where Protocol is something like "Openwire" connections.  There will be an MBean per connection.  Beyond that, there's not a good way to get a total count.

Can you explain more about why your broker is not responding?  By the sounds of it, you've simply hit [Producer Flow Control](http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html).

You also should consider upgrading to ActiveMQ 5.5.  The impact on your code and build should be minimal and consist only of updated client libs for 5.5's activemq-core (and activemq-pool) dependency).

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMX library to retrive Mbean Type = Broker and fetch the attribute TotalConnectionsCount on your Broker.